# How to choose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in backtracking line search method in convex optimization?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, newton-raphson, gradient-descent

I'm using quasi newton method with BFGS update in a convex optimization algorithm,during debugging my algorithm I've noticed that different magnitude of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ has a  great effect on convergence acceleration.As best choice of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ varies for different kinds of optimization problems, I have to choose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for different optimization problems.Can anyone give me some hints on choosing best $\alpha$ and $\beta$?What do they depend on?
The following code segment declares what I mean by $\alpha$ and $\beta$

```
%% Line search

while(f(x+t*delta) > (f(x) + alpha*t*(gradf'*delta)))
    t=beta*t;
end

x=x+t.*delta;
```

Comment: You haven't said anything about the relative cost of objective function and gradient evaluations versus the BFGS calculations.  There's generally a trade-off between more exact line searches (leading to fewer  iterations) and less exact line searches (requiring fewer function evaluations.)  Depending on the cost of your objective function and gradient the most efficient balance can vary.

Comment: @BrianBorchers The objective function is not specified,so I need to change $\alpha$ and $\beta$ according to the objective function.